# Norm of difference in exponential of matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-exponential

I would like to prove that $\|e^A-e^B\| \leq \|A-B\|e^{max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}$, where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

So far I was able to create the first difference term, but I have no idea how to incorporate the max norm.
I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262000/inequality-norm-of-difference-in-exponential-of-matrices?newreg=15d63d96ac0f4ad08a10eb1a97a1a7d4) post, where the Fréchet calculus was mentioned, but I'm still stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get $\|B^k-A^k\|\leq k\|B-A\|(\max(\|A\|,\|B\|))^{k-1}$ as follows

\begin{align*}
    \|B^k-A^k\| &= \left\lVert\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}B^{l}(B-A)A^{k-1-l}\right\rVert
    \leq \sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\left\lVert B^{l}(B-A)A^{k-1-l}\right\rVert\\
    &\leq \sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\|B\|^l\|B-A\|\|A\|^{k-1-l}
     \leq k\|B-A\|\left(\max(\|A\|,\|B\|)\right)^{k-1}
\end{align*}

Then\begin{align*}\|e^B-e^A\|=\left\lVert \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B^k-A^k}{k!}\right\rVert\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k\left(\max(\|A\|,\|B\|)\right)^{k-1}\|B-A\|}{k!}=\left|B-A\right|e^{\max(\|A\|,\|B\|)}\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

So after some sleepless nights I came up with, what I hope is the answer.
First let's use the Taylor series expansion:
$\|e^A-e^B\| = \|\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^k-B^k}{k!}\|$

We can then use the property of the binomial polynoms $(x-y)^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ as
$\|e^A-e^B\| = \|\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(A-B)(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}B+\cdots+AB^{k-2}+B^{k-1})}{k!}\|$.

The norm of product is the product of norm, and the first term is independent of $k$, so I can bring it to the front
$\|e^A-e^B\| = \|A-B\|\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}B+\cdots+AB^{k-2}+B^{k-1})}{k!}\|$, and after that we can apply the inequality of the norm of the sums: $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\|+\|y\|$ as

$\|e^A-e^B\|\leq \|A-B\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\|A\|^{k-1}+\|A\|^{k-2}\|B\|+\cdots+\|A\|\|B\|^{k-2}+\|B\|^{k-1}}{k!}=\|A-B\|S.$
If $\|A\| \geq \|B\|$, then $S\leq\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\|A\|^{k-1}}{k!}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\|A\|^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=e^{\|A\|}$.
Similarly if $\|A\| \leq \|B\|$ then $S \leq e^{\|B\|}$, from which we can state that $S \leq e^{max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}$, for every $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

This proves my initial problem.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you did the first inequality. You would elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: I do not think that the use of identity transforming $x^n-y^n$ is permitted in the case of matrices because we do not know if $A$ and $B$ commute. 
In particular, we have $$(A-B)(A+B)=A^2+AB-BA-B^2=A^2-B^2$$ if an only if $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different proof using integration instead of the Taylor expansion. The key to what follows is the fact that${}^1$ for all $A,B\in\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ and all $t\geq0$
$$
e^{tA}-e^{tB}=\int_0^t e^{(t-s)B}(A-B)e^{sA}\,ds\,.
$$
An easy way to prove this is to re-write this as $e^{-tB}e^{tA}-{\bf1}=\int_0^t e^{-sB}(A-B)e^{sA}\,ds$ and to 1. note that this is true for $t=0$, 2. differentiate after $t$ and see that the two sides are the same.

With this let $\|\cdot\|$ be any norm on $\mathbb C^{m\times m}$ which is submultiplicative (which is a necessary assumption that was also made by the other answers). We combine the above with the standard inequalities
[$\|\int f\,d\mu\|\leq\int\|f\|\,d\mu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819728/) and [$\|e^A\|\leq e^{\|A\|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1080195) to obtain
\begin{align*}
\|e^A-e^B\|&\leq  \int_0^1 \big\|e^{(1-s)B}(A-B)e^{sA} \big\|\,ds\\
&\leq  \int_0^1 \big\|e^{(1-s)B}\big\|\,\|A-B\|\,\big\|e^{sA} \big\|\,ds\tag{1}\\
&\leq  \int_0^1 e^{(1-s)\|B\|}\|A-B\|e^{s\|A\|}\,ds\\
&\leq  \int_0^1 e^{(1-s)\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}\|A-B\|e^{s\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}\,ds\\
&=e^{\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}\|A-B\|\int_0^1 1\,ds=\|A-B\|e^{\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}}
\end{align*}
in the fourth step we used monotonicity of the exponential.

The advantage of this proof is that if you---for whatever reason---have a better grip on $\|e^{(t-s)A}\|,\|e^{sB}\|$ (as opposed to $e^{(t-s)\|A\|},e^{s\|B\|}$), then you can stop at (1) and upper bound the norms of the exponentials to become a better overall estimate. As an example, if $A,B$ are from the unitary algebra $\mathfrak u(n)$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm which outputs the largest singular value, then $e^{(t-s)A},e^{sB}$ are unitary for all $s,t$ and their norm is always $1$. This shows the substantially better bound $\|e^A-e^B\|\leq\|A-B\|$ for this special case.

---

<sub>1: This is a special case of more general identity that is sometimes called "Duhamel's Formula", cf. Ch. 1, Thm. 5.1 in Dollard and Friedman, *Product Integration with Application to Differential Equations*, Cambridge University Press (1984)</sub>